# How to connect to PostgreSQL using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm having trouble connecting to a remote PostgreSQL database using EntityFramework for C#. I'm able to connect to the database with pgAdmin, "SQL Manager for PostgreSQL" (from EMS, www.pgsqlmanager.com) and classic NpgsqlConnection (I can read data and use sqlcommands to insert/modify/delete data).

But when I try to use the EntityFramework I get the message:

"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."
"FATAL: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"...\", user \"...\", database \"...\", SSL off"

I've tried the solution on "http://www.elephantsql.com/docs/appharbor.html" and it didn't work. Placing a breaking point on "return ManifestToken" reveals that this code is never executed, even though "this.AddDependencyResolver(…)" is executed.

The connection opens since "(my context instance).Database.Connection.Open();" doesn't throw any exception.

I've tried the code with the following combination of packages/libraries:

- Npgsql 2.2.7 / Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy 2.2.7 / EntityFramework 4.3.1
- Npgsql 2.2.7 / Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy 2.2.7 / EntityFramework 5.0.0
- Npgsql 2.2.7 / Npgsql.EntityFramework 2.2.7 / EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Npgsql 3.0.3 / EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.0.3 / EntityFramework 6.1.3

None of the above worked (PostgreSQL server is 8.3).

The code works on a replicated MySql remote database.

My guess is that some of the PostgreSQL libraries is trying to query a restricted area of the server, it shouldn't. Others clients work perfectly without doing that.

Some of the code:

```
// This work
using (MyContextClass dbInstance = new (MyContextClass(new NpgsqlConnection(pgConnectionString))))
{
    dbInstance.Database.Connection.Open();
    dbInstance.Database.Connection.Close();
    using(NpgsqlConnection pgCon = new NpgsqlConnection(dbInstance.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        using(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            using(NpgsqlDataAdapter pgAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from someTable", pgCon))
            {
                pgTeste.Open();

                pgAdapter.Fill(dt);

                pgTeste.Close();

                Assert.IsTrue(dt.Rows.Count > 1); // ok
            }
        }
    }    
}

// This doesn't

using (MyContextClass dbInstance = new (MyContextClass(new NpgsqlConnection(pgConnectionString))))
{
    var lst = dbInstance.SomeTableDataSet.ToList(); // Throws exception!!!
}

// This works perfectly

using (MyContextClass dbInstance = new (MyContextClass(new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))))
{
    var lst = dbInstance.SomeTableDataSet.ToList();

    Assert.IsTrue(lst.Count > 1); // ok
}
```

Comment: What does your `pg_hba.conf` file look like? Looks like you will have to edit the permissions and access there.

Comment: I do not have access to the file; the point being that other clients work fine on the same environment.